# How to copy an Ubuntu install from one laptop to another

Tags: system-installation, laptop, clone

I am going to change my machine: from a laptop with Ubuntu to another laptop where I am going to install Ubuntu...

I am quite happy with the current system, what I am afraid of is having to rebuild everything from 0.

So what do people often do to clone an Ubuntu system? That may include the data, packages, shortcut settings, etc...

Comment: Can't you simply extract the HDD from your old laptop and install it on your new laptop? I changed MB, MicroProcessor, RAM and HDD's, just conserving the boot HDD and expected a major issue after the boot, which didn't happen. This may not be really fancy but it works like a charm.

Comment: Or just create a clone of your system with remastersys, UCK, Customizer...

Comment: I did this several times: Plug in the old laptop drive into the new laptop with an USB-to-SATA converter, boot the new laptop from Ubuntu live CD, wipe the new drive with gparted, copy the entire disk from old to new, resize partition, boot, have some biscuit, reconfigure X11. Won't possibly ever happen that easy with Windows!

Comment: whats that part on reconfigure X11 ? Also, is the copy a regular simple copy-paste ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are a few ways to copy your config and set up. It depends on how big the changes you have made. And if you are upgrading to a new version. Some of the methods are useful when upgrading between versions but be careful as they can stop some software form working correctly.

## Method 1: Fresh install

The most robust and stable way is a fresh install and then copy the config and re-install all your packages. This also work from an old version to a new version. There are ways to make this happen quite quickly, and automate most of the process. The slowest part would be having to download all the packages not included in your install media. I had the 8 dvd disk images that allowed me to install much faster then downloading.

I would recommend this option as setting up and install grub, can render your system unusable. You need to have a solid grasp of grub to use method 2.

Before you do your new install (new laptop) you need to copy some information off your old install (old laptop).

### Your setup or configuration

All the files that save your customization are stored in two places. The first and most import is your /home/[username] directory. There can be hundreds of .[package-config-dir] files and directories. I am going to list the most important but you can have more and add more if you want. This process can cause problems with packages not working correctly. So be careful when you do this. Make a back up of you fresh install before you paste your new directories.

These directories and files are not very large, and will probably only take a few hundred megabytes. This method is also useful between upgrades. You can quite quickly copy all the configuration changes you made between Ubuntu versions.

By default most programs create the .[package-config-dir] when they run the first time. If it does not exist it is recreated. You should not rely on this behavior as not all programs will work like this.

1. Using Nautilus, navigate to your home directory (`/home/[username]`)
2. Select "View menu →  Show Hidden Files" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
3. You should now see all the hidden `.*` directories. You might need to do this as root. simply start nautilus as root from a command line.

   Select the following directories and copy them to a separate directory.

   ```
   /home/aaron/.config  
   /home/aaron/.gconf  
   /home/aaron/.gnome2  
   /home/aaron/.gnome2_private  
   /home/aaron/.local  
   /home/aaron/.mozilla
   ```

   I have made changes to these files. So I copy them as well.

   ```
   /home/aaron/.bash_aliases 
   /home/aaron/.bashrc 
   /home/aaron/.vimrc
   ```

   There may be many other packages that you use that don't store the configuration in these directories.  Copy them as well, but be warned if the programs don't work as expected. You might need to restore the `.*` file or directory. You could do this by simply deleting the file or directory, but you should have made a back up before copying over the directories.
4. Depending on how you use your system. You might have made changes to some of the files in the `/etc` directory. If you have you should copy them as well. I create a custom smb.conf file for work and I have many Apache virtual hosts I use for development so I copy them as well.  You could copy your whole `/etc` directory but this can create problems if you machine does not have exactly the same set up in terms of hardware. Which it wont going from one machine to another.

   ```
   /etc/samba/smb.conf
   /etc/hosts
   /etc/apache2 # the whole directory.
   ```

   Copy your config files before or after you install new software. Don't do this while an software package install is currently running. You could break the installation.

### Your installed packages

Using Synaptic you can export all your installed packages quite easily using the export markings menu option.

1. File menu → Save markings as
2. Check "Save full state, not only changes"
3. Choose a name and directory to save this file (You will probably have to put this on a flash drive.)

You can then reload all your installed packages by reversing the process:

1. File menu → Read markings
2. Select the file you created in the first step.

This will probably take the longest. If you download a lot of packages (1Gb of packages), this will take a few hours.

## Method 2: Using disk images

I will make method 2 as a separate post. This is a more advanced option. It requires you understand partitions, install grub, and use the command line.

[How to copy an Ubuntu install from one laptop to another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62340/how-to-copy-an-ubuntu-install-from-one-laptop-to-another/62383#62383)

Comment: What if the last step of restoring Installed Packages fails with these [errors](http://pastebin.com/exZ41uAg)?

Answer (score 38):

There are a few ways to copy your config and set up. It depends on how big the changes you have made. And if you are upgrading to a new version. Some of the methods are useful when upgrading between versions but be careful as they can stop some software from working correctly.

## method 1: Fresh install

Posted separately. [How to copy an Ubuntu install from one laptop to another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62340/how-to-copy-an-ubuntu-install-from-one-laptop-to-another/62374#62374)

This is the safest method and does not require you to edit your grub and boot set up. Easy as most of it can be done using GUI tools.

## method 2: Using disk images

This can be the fastest way to move. As to copy your hard drive partitions as disk images are quite fast. If you don't want to re-install every piece of software. Though creating, resizing and moving the disk images can take quite a long time. I would only recommend this if you are not going to upgrade to a new version of Ubuntu. Make sure you understand disk partitions and grub. Most of what I am doing will use the command line. You need to make sure you understand what a command does before you run it. I am not responsible for data loss as a result of the instructions that follow.

Step one create a disk image of your installation.

Fist we need to get some information about the setup. Using `parted -l` and `mount`

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST9320423AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      32.3kB  197MB   197MB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      197MB   10.2GB  10.0GB  primary   linux-swap(v1)
 3      10.2GB  50.2GB  40.0GB  primary   ext4
 4      50.2GB  299GB   249GB   extended
 5      50.2GB  54.4GB  4195MB  logical   ext4
 6      54.4GB  65.9GB  11.5GB  logical   ext4
 7      65.9GB  299GB   233GB   logical   ext4

$ mount
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda6 on /usr type ext4 (rw)
# I took out the entries that were not need for these instructions

$ cat /etc/fstab 
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
UUID=ddc8c237-e8ac-4038-a0ed-f7c866d6603b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0    1
UUID=aa9881d1-5cc1-4e94-8cd7-8125e18ece2f /boot           ext4    defaults        0      2
UUID=31a6fde1-6b96-4cc3-acfd-88573f52be36 /home           ext4    defaults        0      2
UUID=073146a7-5668-4728-9a6f-1a599f358a8d /usr            ext4    defaults        0      2
UUID=540b96b6-b3c3-4092-b4ad-6b33bcbbe16d none            swap    sw              0      0
```

Your set up might look different. I have a separate partition for `/home`, root (`/`), and `/usr`.

#### Creating the Disk Images

I use `dd` as it is simple and quick. Make sure you read and understand how it works.
You will need an empty partition that is bigger than the entire partition size that you are copying. This can take quite some time. Creating resizing and copying the partitions can take a few hours depending on their size. You will need to replace the external drive with a part to the storage media you will use for this process.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda5 of=/media/externaldrive/sda5-root.img
sudo dd if=/dev/sda7 of=/media/externaldrive/sda7-home.img
sudo dd if=/dev/sda6 of=/media/externaldrive/sda6-usr.img
```

Here is an actual example of out put after running this on my set up.

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda5 of=/media/home0/sda5-root.img
8193087+0 records in
8193087+0 records out
4194860544 bytes (4.2 GB) copied, 55.3159 s, 75.8 MB/s
```

We can reduce the size of this disk image, using the tools provided by Linux.

```
$ sudo resize2fs -P sda5-root.img
 resize2fs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
 Estimated minimum size of the filesystem: 605972
$ ls -sh ./sda5-root.img
 4.0G ./sda5-root.img
$ sudo resize2fs -M sda5-root.img
 resize2fs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
 Please run 'e2fsck -f sda5-root.img' first.
$ sudo e2fsck -fy ./sda5-root.img # y makes it run without asking thousands of questions.
```

`e2fsck` will output lots of errors or fixes necessarily. This is because the information in the file system is no longer correct in terms of where the partition boundaries start and end. This is correct because it is no longer in the partition it was configured for.

```
$ sudo resize2fs -M sda5-root.img
 resize2fs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
 Resizing the filesystem on sda5-root.img to 605505 (4k) blocks.
 Resizing the filesystem on sda5-root.img to 605505 (4k) blocks.
 The filesystem on sda5-root.img is now 605505 blocks long.
$ ls -sh ./sda5-root.img
 2.4G ./sda5-root.img
```

It essentially removes all the free space in the partition. So for the larger partition, this can be more the 50% of the disk size. Much quicker to copy a smaller file

You now need to boot up your new laptop with a live disk and do what follows here. You need to use a live disk as you can not make changes to a running partition that is currently used by the installed operating system.

You can now copy these disk images into the partitions on the new computer. You should have set up these partitions already. Using the live disk and `gparted` is a quick and easy way to do this. Make sure you have all the partitions your system requires. You can make these partitions larger than the ones you had on your previous system. When we copy the disk images into them, we will resize the file system and it will take up all the free space on the partition.

Now step two: copying the disk images on to the new drive and into the new partitions.

```
sudo dd if=/media/exteranldrive/sda5-root.img of=/dev/sda3 # replace the [sda3] with your partition.
```

On my machine, this is what the output looked like

```
$ sudo dd if=./sda5-root.img of=/dev/sdb6 
4844040+0 records in  
4844040+0 records out  
2480148480 bytes (2.5 GB) copied, 87.4921 s, 28.3 MB/s  

$ sudo fsck.ext4 -fy /dev/sdb6  
e2fsck 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)  
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes  
Pass 2: Checking directory structure  
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity  
Pass 4: Checking reference counts  
Pass 5: Checking group summary information  
root1: 50470/504000 files (1.4% non-contiguous), 616736/2060328 blocks
```

Now we need to edit the fstab file to point to the correct devices.
If you have just copied the new disk partition on to your new disk, the fstab file is on that partition so you need to mount it in order to access the file. You will also need to have the root partition mounted in order to install grub if you don't have a separate boot partition.

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/tmp  
mount /dev/sdb6 /mnt/tmp  
$ sudo blkid  # to see what the disk uuid is   
/dev/sda5: LABEL="root1" UUID="ddc8c237-e8ac-4038-a0ed-f7c866d6603b" TYPE="ext4"  
/dev/sdb6: LABEL="root1" UUID="ddc8c237-e8ac-4038-a0ed-f7c866d6603b" TYPE="ext4"  
$ gksu gedit /mnt/tmp/etc/fstab  
replace the UUID with the UUID of your partition  
UUID=ddc8c237-e8ac-4038-a0ed-f7c866d6603b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0  1
```

Here you can see that the new disk image that I copied across to the other disk has the same UUID as the the original file system. So you could copy your fstab file form your old install across into your new install and have a working system. That will boot. On my set up I can't leave my computer like this or it will boot to whichever device it finds first.

Edit fstab and make sure the uuid match the partitions that you have set up for root and home and whatever other partition you set up.

Last step is to install grub on you new disk.

```
sudo chroot /mnt/tmp # your root partition.   
grub-install /dev/XXX
```

In my case:

```
grub-install /dev/sdb
update-grub
```

Please read these instructions before beginning. It is no use having all the data on your new laptop and not being able to boot it up.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: I had a doubt, if the target partition has more space than the disk image, will dd allow us to use the additional space or will that be wasted?

Comment: @nikhil. No dd will not use the additional space. But it is not designed to. It does not understand file systems. fsck.ext4 on the other had does understand partitions and files systems. Part of the file system check is to check partition size, and make sure the file system matches the partition size.

Comment: in my case, I use ubuntu 18.04 live cd and do any thing, in final step, I installed boot-repair for help me fix /boot, everything work fine, thank you very much - nelaaro

Comment: Note, I had to bind directories for grub `sudo mount –bind /dev /mnt/dev && sudo mount –bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts && sudo mount –bind /proc /mnt/proc && sudo mount –bind /sys /mnt/sys` as well as mount my EFI partition within chroot `mount /dev/XXX /mnt` where XXX is EFI partition (not root/home/swap etc) sources: https://blog.cadena-it.com/linux-tips-how-to/how-to-repair-restore-or-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd-or-usb/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405525

Comment: if you follow the instructions in the answer, you'd need to make all those paths `/mnt/tmp`

Answer (score 12):

Try clonezilla. Clonezilla is a disk imaging/clonning tool. You can use this tool to clone your Ububtu to a new system.

[image: clonezilla boot menu]

Clonezilla clones your settings and also your entire partitions.

There are two versions of clonezilla available. Clonezilla live is suitable for a single time use.

For further information visit this [link](https://clonezilla.org/).

Comment: Good option. Remember, restoring on dissimilar hardware may not be that easy. I guess it should be okay, if you restore to a partition of same size. You can also try PING (Partition-Image-Is-Not-Ghost). Thats another tool.

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR;

Upon further reading, the rsync method below will likely take more time and may be incomplete (for instance, booting may not work after so files will need to be updated such as fstab). I may update this answer in the future but for now just see [Copy the entire root directory (/) for transferring OS to new computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280602/copy-the-entire-root-directory-for-transferring-os-to-new-computer) OR
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608131/backup-and-restore-of-root-file-system-ubuntu-20-04

This will backup your entire root directory (notice `/` is used before `/Drive` which is where you're backing up to) and notify when complete for ten seconds (see `man rsync` for details about the options used before running)

```
sudo rsync -aAXHS --info=progress2 --delete --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*", "/Drive", "/lost+found"} / /Drive && notify-send -t 10000 "Backup complete"
```

If that doesn't work for you this should

```
sudo rsync -aAXHS --info=progress2 --delete --exclude "/dev/*" --exclude "/proc/*" --exclude "/sys/*" --exclude "/tmp/*" --exclude "/run/*" --exclude "/mnt/*" --exclude "/media/*" --exclude "/Drive" --exclude "/lost+found" / /Drive && notify-send -t 10000 "Backup complete"
```

Use an alias for this command to shorten the keystrokes by putting the following in your `.bashrc`

```
alias backup='sudo rsync -aAXHS --info=progress2 --delete --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*", "/USBDrive", "/lost+found"} / /USBDrive && notify-send -t 10000 "Backup complete"'
```

To restore the backup, just reverse the source and destination paths in the above command.

Please be mindful that this is suitable for local and stand-alone systems only. If your system is being actively accessed by some other systems on the network, it is not a better solution.

Because, the contents of the systems might be constantly updated every minute, and some files may change during the rsync process.

Say for example, when rsync will reach the file 2, the contents of the previous file (File 1) might be changed. This will leave you with a dependency error when you will need to use that backup.

In such cases, a snapshot-based backup is the better approach. Because the system will get "froze" before the backup process starts and get it "unfreeze" when the backup process finishes, so all the files are consistent.

### Details (rsync method)

I looked into Clonezilla but currently, incremental/differential backups are not supported as seen [here](https://clonezilla.org/#limitations).
This means that every time you back up your system you will have to create a new image. This isn't efficient if you will be backing up your system often.

It looks like the accepted answer in this post will work but here are some more options; borrowing some ideas from the accepted answer. The accepted answer will not back up any repositories you have cloned into your system.

If you had to build any programs after cloning then you will have to do that over again. It may be true that this will not be as robust and stable as the accepted answer. But I think these are worth trying, especially if you have spent a lot of time building programs from source, for example.

Another advantage to these options below is they should work on many Linux distributions. Worst case, it doesn't work and then you can do the accepted answer (assuming you made a backup of your new installation first or you haven't changed the new installation enough to care if you have to install it again).

As described in the accepted answer, if some of your programs aren't working, you could try restoring the .* file or directory which is the package configuration file or directory for most programs. You could do this by simply deleting the file or directory and then running the respective program again. If the following concerns you from the accepted answer, "You could copy your whole /etc directory but this can create problems if your machine does not have the same setup in terms of hardware. Which it won't go from one machine to another." Then you could manually copy specific /etc directories separately or utilize section 3.9, Advanced usage of filter rules, described below. I think the section, "Your installed packages", in the accepted answer isn't required with the methods below. As stated in the accepted answer, "Copy your config files before or after you install new software. Don't do this while a software package install is currently running. You could break the installation."

I found [this post](https://ostechnix.com/backup-entire-linux-system-using-rsync/) which uses the rsync command (which should work on most Linux distributions).

But the only things I think you need to know from this post (since the source in this link describes this in more detail) are the following:

- Please be mindful that this is suitable for local and stand-alone systems only. If your system is being actively accessed by some other systems on the network, it is not a better solution. Because, the contents of the systems might be constantly updated every minute, and some files may change during the rsync process.
- Say for example, when rsync will reach file 2, the contents of the previous file (File 1) might be changed. This will leave you with a dependency error when you will need to use that backup. In such cases, a snapshot-based backup is the better approach. Because the system will get "frozen" before the backup process starts and get it "unfreezes" when the backup process finishes, all the files are consistent.
- First, insert your backup medium (USB thumb drive or External hard disk). Then find the drive letter using the 'fdisk -l' command. In my case, my Pen drive id is /dev/sdb1. Mount your drive to any location of your choice. I am going to mount it under /mnt. $ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
- In one of the comments, somebody says: "SK, I appreciate your efforts. However, IMHO you should make it more forcefully clear to your readers that RSYNC is not a suitable complete disk backup solution. It is an excellent FILE backup utility. However, it’s not a suitable DISK backup utility. The reason why is a disk must be un-mounted before backing up or there is a very high chance of file corruption on restore."
- In another comment, someone says: “It doesn’t matter if your hard drive is a different size, or use a different filesystem.” Au contraire. Rsync is great, but it does matter about the destination file system. For instance, using rsync to back up files in an ext4 file system to a FAT file system, would mean loss of file ownership and permission information. The destination file system needs to have at least the capabilities of the source file system.
- A tip from a commenter: To be on the safe side with open files or ones that may change, you could always switch to runlevel 1 before starting the backup.

For me, external drives are mounted under /media/$USER if I right-click the drive in nautilus and then click mount.

Other than that, you'll want to read most of section 3 for the numerous backup options available to you [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rsync#Full_system_backup)
In my case, I went with 3.7 and 3.8, which is what is outlined at ostechnix.com. I recommend reading 3.7, Full system backup, 3.8, Restore backup, and 3.9, Advanced usage of filter rules, at the very least as it goes into more detail than ostechnix.com. Section 3.6, Snapshot backup might be what you want if your system is being actively accessed by some other systems on the network, as described in the first point above.
I considered section 4, File system cloning, but upon further reading, [this article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Disk_cloning) says:
Tip: Over time file systems get new features and the mkfs utilities change their defaults, but not all new features can be enabled without reformatting. So, when moving data to a new drive, instead of cloning the block devices or file systems, consider creating a new file system and only copy the files (and their attributes, ACLs, extended attributes, etc.) with e.g. rsync.

Answer (score 0):

**Use GParted** ([detailed instruction](https://www.diskpart.com/clone/clone-partition-gparted-7201.html))

1. Boot from Ubuntu live USB
2. Run GParted
3. Select the partition you want to copy and choose "Copy" in context menu.
4. Select unallocated space in target disk and choose "Paste" in context menu.
5. Resize new partition if need.
6. Press Apply button.
7. Restore GRUB (simple way is [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair))