# Is there a way to copy installed application into another OS?

Tags: 13.10, laptop, software-installation, .desktop, migration

I have Ubuntu 13.10 on both of My Laptop and PC. I've installed many applications on my PC.
I don't want to download all these apps again and reinstall them on Laptop. What method should I take to copy installed app into another Ubuntu?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but this might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62340/how-to-copy-an-ubuntu-install-from-one-laptop-to-another/62383#62383

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this link contain the APTonCD tutorial , this application does exactly what you need

http://www.howtogeek.com/110034/how-to-back-up-restore-your-installed-ubuntu-packages-with-aptoncd/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use Clonezilla.

http://clonezilla.org/