# Any way to "Export" Lubuntu?

Tags: usb, lubuntu

Is there any way to 'copy' or 'export' Lubuntu to a USB-drive so I can use it on another PC without having to set it up ?

Comment: like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-an-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-installer-bootable-usb

Comment: You might also take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/62383/157741)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "clone" the installation to the USB, but it'll not work if the computers are not of one type - driver errors.

Comment: Well I guess that answers my question, For people that didn't understand I meant to 'export' an os that's already installed on my hard drive.

Comment: Actually, odds are it _will_ work if the drive is properly set up so it would boot. More likely than not, Ubuntu will load the right modules for the new hardware.