# Is there a way to clone my desktop ubuntu to my laptop?

Tags: 14.04, migration

I've been transitioning to Ubuntu for the last year and have my main PC running Ubuntu as the only OS now.

My issue is that I will going on the road for 2 months and taking my desktop PC with me is obviously not an option.

I have a laptop that I'm happy to wipe. Is it feasible to take an image of my desktop PC before I leave and transfer it to this laptop when I leave (and then when I return to reverse the process and put my laptop's image back onto my desktop PC?

I'm looking to transfer all directories such as `/etc` (for apache/phpmyadmin for example) as well as `/home`.

Answer (score -1):

[How to make a disk image and restore from it later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later)

-This may help, if you're looking to make a disk image of your whole system, therefore allowing you to restore another machine using the image.

Comment: Thanks very much - I've done things like this in Windows, however I know that can cause problems with desktop/laptop harware/driver conflicts. Is this a problem with Ubuntu too?

Comment: Yes, this can be a problem - however if you ensure that you have the same version of ubuntu on your laptop prior to the swap, the system **should** auto-detect hardware changes and download the appropriate drivers (assuming you are connected to the internet). If not, manually installing any missing drivers is easily done with a quick google search. I've done this a few times without problems, so good luck!

Comment: additionally: another option for you to consider is `dd`, which is well explained here -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/62340/how-to-copy-an-ubuntu-install-from-one-laptop-to-another/62383#62383