# Ubuntu migrate to same computer after GPT partitioning

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, hard-drive, migration

Currently my hard-drive is set to MBR and I want to change it to GPT which will naturally entail wiping of the hard-drive. I want to keep my Ubuntu install for which I plan to follow [Official Ubuntu /home migration guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to transfer my /home to my external drive but as I understand it will cause permission problems if set as /home mount in my new Ubuntu installation since the new user's ID will not be the same as the current one. I've also looked at [this excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62340/how-to-copy-an-ubuntu-install-from-one-laptop-to-another/62383#62383) but it still leaves me with the user permissions question. How can I migrate to a new OS on the same machine without having to worry about user permissions?

Comment: Just use the same user-name, you will not have permission-problems

Comment: @mook765 using the Ubuntu guide or the answer on AskUbuntu?

Comment: If your hard-drive has MBR, Ubuntu is installed in legacy-mode. If you convert the drive to GPT you would have to reinstall, but in UEFI-mode. When you move your /home-partition to external drive before, just set the mount-point for this partition to /home and untick the formatting-checkbox during install. Use the same user-name as before. I run different distros, all of them point to the same folders, all distros use same username, user-id is 1000 on fresh install, so all distros have same user-id as well.

Comment: @mook765 I read somewhere that there's no compulsion to install UEFI with GPT

Comment: Why do you convert to GPT, there is not much advantage from doing that.

Comment: I'm hackintoshing☺

Comment: UEFI lives from GPT, legacy from MBR, if you mix that up then do not cry when you run in problems.