# How to get all customizations of a stock Ubuntu so I can duplicate them on another box?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, upgrade, customization

I've got a workstation running Ubuntu 16.04 that I've been using awhile, and as per the normal behavior here at the company I work, I've installed both (development) team required tools and random stuff that I use.  Also dotfiles.  Also alternatives. Also ppas.  Also various edits to files in /etc.  Also python packages.  Also ... and so on.

Is there a way I can get all the customizations I've made? I.e., stuff that didn't happen out of the box? So I can duplicate this on a new box.  (Or this box after I flatten it.) A list would be sufficient (don't need, e.g., a script).

Looking for a tool/a procedure/a checklist that could get me going.

(I looked over the first couple of pages of "popular tags" and didn't see anything that looked really appropriate - sorry!)

**Update**: Very sorry I forgot to mention: I can't do a clone.  This workstation is no longer really working right and I don't know how to get it back to a clean state.  In particular I've installed and uninstalled various NVidia drivers and CUDA releases so many times over the course of the year that I can in fact no longer build using CUDA.  So I must flatten it and start over.

I'm going to look at the Q&A @Raffa pointed to in the comments ... but maybe there's been some more knowledge gained/more tools written/more blog posts in the past 8 years so I'll leave this question up ...

Comment: Isn't cloning to/from an image an option?

Comment: You could possibly take a look at [https://askubuntu.com/questions/62340/how-to-copy-an-ubuntu-install-from-one-laptop-to-another]

Comment: A fresh install on the other box will give you a stock Ubuntu there. Nothing systematically tracks what you have been adding, so there will be no automated way of undoing eveything you ever changed to the system.