# Moving Ubuntu from HDD to SSD/HDD Combo

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

Currently Dual booting Ubuntu 18.04.3 and Windows 10, however I realized a bit too late that I put my Ubuntu installation only on my HDD, making it a bit slow/laggy. I'd like to migrate the installation onto my SSD for the faster boot time and general responsiveness and whatnot without having to reinstall Ubuntu all over again, while keeping most of the contents such as general files and applications on my HDD due to my small SSD size. Is there a way to do that?

Alternatively, if my only option is to reinstall, is there a way to remove the Ubuntu installation without having to fix the boot loader? I don't have an optical drive in my device and don't have access to any flash drives for the time being. Note that it's a UEFI system, so in theory I should just be able to move the Windows boot loader to the top and simply re-do the installation of Ubuntu in the appropriate drives, right?

Comment: Do you have space available on your SSD? On most like setups I have seen, the SSD is sized to hold Windows...and little else.

Comment: @user535733 I have around 50-60GB free on my 128GB SSD, yes. I only use it for a limited number of applications, aside from my Windows installation.

Comment: Without flash drive(s) for repairs and unless you have good backups of both Windows & Ubuntu data on flash drives also, you should not be making any system changes. I prefer new install and move data from old install to new /home or data partition(s). To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question was already answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62340/how-to-copy-an-ubuntu-install-from-one-laptop-to-another) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62340/how-to-copy-an-ubuntu-install-from-one-laptop-to-another/62383#62383), but like everything Linux there are a number of ways to do what you're asking.

I hope that helps.