# Copy the entire root directory (/) for transferring OS to new computer?

Tags: transfer, migration

Probably that's an odd question, I'm sorry.
Can I copy my Ubuntu 20.04 os to another computer (completely, I would like to include everything out of the box) just copying my `/` directory? If I want to transfer everything on a new computer, can I simply copy/paste my `/` directory on the new computer?

Thanks

**EDIT**: Another question, let me explain my situation. I have several files in the root directories and not only in my home directory that I want to backup, some of them are simply changes to config files, some of them are new files, but I don't know exactly which file is modified/new. I want to move to another computer, and I would like to have the same os working on my actual computer, changing only the hardware. How can I do it? I thought the easy way would be copy-pasting the directories

Comment: No. "cp" will mess up permissions if you do not use the settings to preserve them. But there is a better tool for this: disk dump (`dd` is the command). Boot from a live session, 'dd` your partitions onto an external disk and you can reuse that disk dump to put it on another system. Mind that I would advice to not do this: make a backup of PERSONAL files and just reinstall the system. a bit more work but you can automate all your alterations you want to make

Comment: I am using `cp -a` with no problems. `dd` is not so good for this purpose.

Comment: I got confused about why everyone was recommending dd for backup until I re-read the question and it's not about backup, it's about migrating a working OS to another computer, so I made a suggested edit to the title

Comment: OP, why not physically remove the system drive from computer A and place it into computer B?  That would be faster than dd and avoid the problem of the target drive being a different size.

Comment: @thomasrutter... same computer... is in a few of the comments..... "essentially" a new computer since it will be TOTALLY reloaded.. but it is the same physical machine... apparently

Comment: Then dd or clonezilla is probably best, but I don't understand OP's reason for transferring it at all, or saying that it's to a "new computer".  OP seems to have mislead us, or at best left out important details, in the question and it's affected people's ability to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: @thomasrutter I’m sorry, I was trying to simplify the question

Comment: OP, why are you doing this, and what did you mean in that comment where you said "'m doing this process on the same computer, I want to clean my entire drive from every partition, then install there only my old Ubuntu with everything that it has now".  What is it you actually want to achieve?  It sounds like what you're proposing is a no-op.

Comment: @thomasrutter Practically, I want to make a restorable backup of every file that I have even in root paths. I already used Clonezilla but since the docs sucks and I don’t know if it works, I asked this to search for a simpler way. The question was at first misleading, then I corrected myself through comments and edit.

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather just copy the entire drive, with drive space not being so costly anymore.

I am a proponent of using `dd` in these situations whenever possible.
*(Though I've gotten away with it mounted and in use, copying the root system should probably be done via a live CD/USB)*
*(All the device/directory names used below are arbitrary)*

Option 1) I would copy the drive to an iso.
`dd if=/dev/sda of=/someotherlargedrive/backupname.iso bs=4M status=progress`

To restore that image back on a drive.
`dd if=/someotherlargedrive/backupname.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress`

**OR**

Option 2) I would copy the ubuntu partition to an iso.
`dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/someotherlargedrive/backupname.iso bs=4M status=progress`

To restore the image back on a partition
`dd if=/someotherlargedrive/backupname.iso of=/dev/sdc1 bs=4M status=progress`

*!!!Keep in mind that if only cloning a partition, there may be other necessary partitions like "/boot" that may need to be considered depending on the situation.*

**OR**

Option 3) I would copy the entire drive to another drive, creating a usable bootable clone.
`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress`

**OR**

Option 4) I'd just take the hard drive out of the one PC and put it into the new one... Other than things like graphics and other manually downloaded drivers, the [LINUX] drive should transfer operationally with little to no reconfiguration.

**OR**

sidebar....Depending on the application and the urgency for portability, I may consider using VMs, as they are easily cloned (or just copied with the cp command)... So the PC itself is basically a file and portable to another host running the virtualization software. I have dd'ed  physical boxes into images for VMs(and sometimes directly onto VMs) and have taken copies of my Desktop PC elsewhere around the house and to work & travel on a laptop.

Comment: For the second solution, if I copy ubuntu making an iso, can I burn it into a usb to install it somewhere else?

Comment: you cannot "install" it.. but you can copy it "somewhere else" like i detailed there in the "restore" part. You will basically be cloning it to your new partition in the new location (you would "effectively" be installing it, but install means something different, so we wont use that word)..... but again, be aware of the warning I put there about partitions... if have any other directories mounted on separate partitions like /boot, /home, etc... those will not come and you will need to copy those too, separately. But If all your directories are mounted under "/", then it's pretty automatic.

Comment: I know that `.iso` files are meant to be burnt on a drive to be installed and I thought that that process would make me have an `ubuntu.iso` image to burn it and install just like you have the basic image to make the first ubuntu install, but I think I'm wrong. 
I have everything mounted under `/`. I'm doing this process on the same computer, I want to clean my entire drive from every partition, then install there only my old Ubuntu with everything that it has now, so I need to be sure that everything goes right

Comment: yes that is wrong in this case, .iso = image... you will have an "image" of your partition using option 2... Do you have another drive in your machine or external that is going to be large enough to store the whole partition? can you show the output of `df -h` ...or maybe a snapshot of the gnome-disks utility?

Comment: I have an external drive to which I would put my backup

Comment: looking at your comment... you are trying to wipe your entire drive and reinstall what you already have for ubuntu... that requires more than option 2... you most likey will not be able to boot back into ubuntu without fixing some things. It seems your real goal is to clean other stuff off of your other partitions????? You should probably look into the best way to do that instead???? If not that, and if nothing else, use option 3 and replace your current drive with the backup... then experiment with that one instead, until you are comfortable

Comment: When I boot I have an option (PopOS) that I deleted, idk why it's still there, and I would like to clean it before making a dual boot with Windows. My idea was to backup ubuntu, dump the drive, reinstall ubuntu with an usb if necessary and then restore my backup

Comment: I need the backup in order to have it in case if I fuck up everything doing the dual boot, so I decided to backup ubuntu anyway and, since I have a backup, just remove everything on my drive and reinstall it

Comment: ok... you have a few things going on that is going to make this not as easily explainable as just restoring a backup... it's almost becoming a different question. Doing a backup image..simple.. restoring ...simple... but now you want to restore you reinstall the system... and now AFTER you dual boot... because you need to do Windows FIRST.... i think there is a lot you should understand before you do that.. do you know all the nuances???

Comment: the dual boot is a separate thing, now I only have to know how to backup everything and restore it is case something goes wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113804/discussion-between-wu-tang-and-fedeubuntu).

Answer (score 3):

Dont't.

It is a waste of time.

Making a backup of your operating system is time consuming. Your backup is quickly obsolete. Operating systems come for free and install in less than an hour. The operating system you install in the future will be better than the one you are considering to backup now.

**Instead invest this time and effort in a good backup of your user data.**

Your user data are unique.

They do not exist anywhere else on this planet.

Once lost, they are lost forever.

Having a good backup of your data anytime is therefore priority number 1, and essentially your *single only* concern when you work with computers.

With that out of the way, **no**, it is not just a matter of copying and pasting an operating system to a new computer to have an operational system on your new computer.

Comment: @fedeubuntu IMO, although `wu-tang's` answer is technically correct, I would go with `vanadium's` answer. You can backup your `/home` directory (or any other directories) with `Back in time` or with any similar programs; where you can (1) excludes the directories that you do not want to include in a snapshot / backup, and (2) setup scheduled snapshots among other things. You should save these snapshots on a different internel or on an external drive.

Comment: I actually agree somewhat with this but there are just use cases where it is not feasible. I don't really know if the OP truly has one, not my call. But, for instance, I cannot stand re-configing my raspberry pi after a power outage... it runs about 5 services and even with the old config files backed up it still takes hours to get it back onlline. Drivers have to be downloaded, workarounds remembered, PPDs, new ssh keys, etc... no thanks! If it doesn't create a huge inconvenience then yeah i use it as an opportunity to upgrade. But i do keep a backup iso or virtual of most of my machines.

Comment: Sometimes you just need an OS configured as you want, and use it for years since you don't need anything else. In my job, where computers are old and used for a single purpose, it's easier to just create an image with clonezilla and in case of trouble it just takes a few minutes to have a clean an usable system.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity fully agree, but as the question is asked now, it appears to be a typical Ubuntu 20.04 user wanting to transfer a working system to another computer. In that case, it is not worth the hassle. Transferring the image of the system to another computer may, depending on the hardware, not work, or at least not without additional technical interventions.

Answer (score 2):

Using rsync you can backup entire root partition content to remote location or any device.

```
sudo rsync -aAXv / --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} <remote location or any drive location>
```

Here you don't need to backup `/dev/,/proc,/sys,/run/,/mnt,/media,/lost+found` and ignore it. These partitions are not preferred because they content details which can be different to system to system according to installation and backuping them won't help to restore in another system or you might messed up if you restore backup in another system.

Comment: This is another good way.

Comment: Then how can I restore it on another computer?

Comment: Just rsync it directly to the drive you want to transfer it to.  You have to have partitioned the target drive how you want it, your fstab probably won't work after, and booting won't either.  It's going to be easier for you in the long run to reinstall and just copy over your personal files, but dd would be second best.

Answer (score 1):

Copying a working system to another computer is possible (at least sometimes, I have tried it two times with success), however, it is not simple and it is sometimes a trial-and-error approach to get the copied system to boot.

First, before making a copy it's best to boot from a live DVD or USB so that filesystems on your disk are not actively used. There are system files (eg. logs) that are modified constantly while the system is running, so you won't copy them properly if you boot from the same system you are trying to copy.

Second, instead of using `cp` I suggest to `tar` every filesystem and un-`tar` it on the target computer onto appropriate partition (also using live DVD/USB for this purpose). This preserves permissions, links, special files like devices, pipes etc.

Third, after having everything copied to the target computer you will anyway need to adjust some crucial configuration files (like `/etc/fstab`), otherwise your copied system will not boot. You may need to generate a new initramfs as well. And surely, you will need to reinstall GRUB on the new system.

These are just general hints; if you don't fully understand what do I mean by the above, I suggest you don't try this because it requires at least average knowledge of the mechanisms how the system boots, how the filesystems are mounted etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But you need to use `cp -a` command to preserve permissions.

Comment: And then I just need to paste every directory inside `/` of the new computer?

Comment: Not "paste" but copy it back the same way.

Comment: are you 100% sure? did you personally try it? in reality, i have to do it on the same computer so i need to be sure nothing goes wrong

Comment: User wants to copy entire system across, so this will be inadequate because it won't transfer partitions, partition UUIDs, boot sector (if MBR), UEFI boot menu entry (if UEFI) and so on, that will all need to be done manually.  At minimum, fstab and boot would need to be manually repaired after doing this.  It's not going to be easy.  Reinstall is best, followed by dd of entire drive.